# Integrity Error when creating multiple records with Flask SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a function that creates some new DB entries in Flask app with SQL Alchemy

```
def add_volunteer_client_record(volunteer_id, **kwargs):
    try:
        volunteer_client = VolunteerClient(volunteer_id=volunteer_id, **kwargs)

        volunteer_report_action_items = VolunteerReportActionItems(volunteer_client_id = volunteer_client.id)

        db_session.add(volunteer_client) 
        db_session.add(volunteer_report_action_items)
        db_session.commit()

        return volunteer_client
    except IntegrityError as e:
        db_session.rollback()
        message = "Integrity error occurred"
        raise BadRequestError(messages={'volunteer_client': [message]})
```

**volunteer_client** gets created fine but when **volunteer_report_action_items** is added to the session I received an IntegrityError and I can not quite understand why.

**My Models**

```
class VolunteerClient(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'volunteer_client'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    volunteer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('provider_user.user_id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='RESTRICT'), unique=True)
    client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='RESTRICT'), unique=True)
```

```
class VolunteerReportActionItems(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'volunteer_report_action_items'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, index=True)
    volunteer_client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('volunteer_client.id', onupdate='CASCADE', ondelete='RESTRICT'))
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.volunteer_client
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  volunteer_id integer NOT NULL,
  client_id integer NOT NULL,
  created_by text,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_by text,
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  UNIQUE(volunteer_id, client_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_volunteer_client_volunteer FOREIGN KEY (volunteer_id)
      REFERENCES public.user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_volunteer_client_client FOREIGN KEY (client_id)
      REFERENCES public.user (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

ALTER TABLE public.volunteer_client OWNER to navigate;
```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.volunteer_report_action_items
(
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  volunteer_client_id integer NOT NULL,
  created_by text,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_by text,
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT fk_volunteer_report_action_items_volunteer_client FOREIGN KEY (volunteer_client_id)
      REFERENCES public.volunteer_client (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
      ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

ALTER TABLE public.volunteer_report_action_items OWNER to navigate;
```

Any help or advice here would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flush the `VolunteerClient` to be able to access the `VolunteerClient.id`

```
def add_volunteer_client_record(volunteer_id, **kwargs):
    try:
        volunteer_client = VolunteerClient(volunteer_id=volunteer_id, **kwargs)
        db_session.add(volunteer_client)
        db_session.flush() 
        volunteer_report_action_items = VolunteerReportActionItems(volunteer_client_id = volunteer_client.id)
        db_session.add(volunteer_report_action_items)
        db_session.commit()
    ...
```

Comment: unreal it worked! Why the need for a flush?

Comment: Your `id` column is a primary key generated by the database. When you `flush` the `VolunteerClient` gets added to the transaction buffer and SQLAlchemy will retrieve the next value in the primary key sequence. Without doing the flush you're not getting a value for the `id`.